# Is there a way to only allow access to an Azure Web app to users coming from specific referral domains?

Tags: azure

I want to only allow users from my own IP and two domains which would cover the client's intranet and external secure website. Should I be doing it in web.config? Azure itself?

Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1):

The mechanism to control which referral domains are allowed to access resources in your Azure Web App, or any other HTTP endpoint for that matter, is called Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

CORS is an IETF standard [(RFC6454)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454) and is supported and configurable for any Web App / App Service.  However, it will not help you in what you are trying to achieve.

Web browsers nowadays operate what's referred to as same-origin policy.  This is where a browser will only fetch resources from the same domain present in the address bar.  Why?  It's really a security mechanism designed to protect the user against cross-site scripting (CSS) attacks, where a malicious actor may craft scripts to make calls to websites a victim is currently logged in to, where their cookie will automatically be sent to the server to sign in, thus being able to carry out activities as the victim.  CORS allows developers to permit cross-origin requests safely by white-listing particular domains which *are* allowed to access resources.

CORS should not be used a mechanism to restrict access to a site.  Neither should the referrer HTTP header be used when locking down access to a website, since this can easily be spoofed.  Further, CORS operates on an honorary basis meaning that, should origin be indeterminable, the request will be allowed, as it is assumed that the request is same-origin, or initial.

What you are looking for is IP restrictions.  Azure Web Apps support IP restrictions.  In the portal, navigate to your Web App -> Networking -> IP Restrictions.  This area will allow you to configure IP addresses or ranges that are allowed to access the application.  You will need to create a rule allowing your IP address and addresses relating to the "referral domains" in question, which demands that the users are coming from known addresses.

So, to answer your question, it should be done in the portal, and you should use IP restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for this, great answer. I know I can restrict traffic to specific IPs via networking and that covers part of my challenge because I have the VPN gateway IP. But the client also wants to allow people who come to the app from another password-protected app which they could be using on any device that we don't know the IP address of.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a Solution for this? I am dealing with a similar challenge at the moment.

Comment: In light of the expanded requirements - the source IP address being dynamic - the only way to restrict access is by authenticating the user with some credential.  There are too many unknowns to recommend a type of auth, but what you should know is that app service can be integrated with Azure AD, and if the clients are members of a synchronized domain then perhaps you could use this and even implement single sign-on.